# How to get the best performance from LINQ querying several rows in a table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

my goal is to get lots of rows from a translation table. I use an ID to get a subset of the table (say 50 rows) then I use another ID to the rows I want from this subset. Using typed datasets I do the following to get the main dataset:

```
funderTextsDS.tbl_funderTextsDataTable fd = 
(funderTextsDS.tbl_funderTextsDataTable)(new funderTextsDSTableAdapters.tbl_funderTextsTableAdapter()).GetData();
```

Then for each value I want to get:

```
fd.Select("eng_code = '" + element + "' and funderID = '" + funderID + "'")[0]["funderText"].ToString();
```

Using ANTS profiler to check the code I found that this method used about 170ms over 10 page refreshes (220 calls to the fd.select...)

When I rewrote this to LINQ it took more than 2000ms to do the same work. Here is the LINQ code I used:

```
IrmDatabaseContext irmDB = new IrmDatabaseContext();
irmDB.tbl_funderTexts.Single(f => f.funderID == funderId && f.eng_code == element).funderText;
```

Anyone have a good way of doing this with LINQ? By looking into sql server profiler i saw that the LINQ actually generated a single select for each text i retrieved. (ie LINQ= 220 selects from the db, tableadapter method = 10 selects)

Solution: 
After having read around the net I found that David B was on the right track, although the for loop threw me off for quite a while. Anyway, the trick as he said, is to use a list as this actually forces linq to run the query against the DB and cache it localy. http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2007/07/17/linq-to-sql-caching-the-query-execution.aspx.

So my solution ended up like this:

```
List<tbl_funderText> fd = (from tf in irmDB.tbl_funderTexts
                      where tf.funderID == (int)cpcrow.cpc_fundingPartnerID
                      select tf).ToList();
```

Then everytime I want an element I do:

```
fd.Single(f => f.eng_code == element).funderText;
```

Analyzing with ANTS I then found that time was reduced to 150ms (about the same as the tableAdapter. SQL query analyzer shows that the SQL is run only one time.

Comment: Could someone format this a bit better so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so in the TableAdapter method, you're pulling rows into memory and then querying those in-memory rows further.  That's easy to do in LINQ.

```
myDataContext dc = new myDataContext();
List<FunderText> myList = myDataContext.tbl_funderTexts.ToList();

List<string> result1 = new List<string>();
foreach(var theValue in myValues)
{
  result1.Add(
    myList.First(f => f.funderID == theValue.funderId && f.eng_code == element).funderText
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do here. Why are you looping? I want a single value, Although I want 22 single values, 22 different places in the code (and they are not sorted). 

What is "myValues"?

Comment: You don't have to loop, I just thought your 22 values might have been collected.  I did want to point out First over Single (single will throw if there are two or more matches).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but try and use a .where instead of .single. Somthing like this:

```
var data = mDB.tbl_funderTexts.where(f => f.funderID == funderid && f.eng_code == element)
var fundertext = data.single().funderText
```

Comment: Actually, Single(predicate) should be preferred over Where(predicate).Single(), since it allows identity cache usage without round trip. See connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362313